# Reduced row echelon form of an augmented matrix is not unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am given a sysetem of linear equations which after graphing, have no solution (the three lines intersect at different points). Now I am trying to prove this algebraically.

As an augmented matrix,

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        1 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & 3 & 6\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

- $R_{1}-R_{2} \Rightarrow R_{2}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & -2 & 2\\
        2 & 3 & 6\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

continue from here in $(1)$ or $(2)$

---

$(1)$

- $R_{1}-\frac{1}{2}R_{3} \Rightarrow R_{3}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & -2 & 2\\
        0 & -\frac{5}{2} & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

- $-\frac{1}{2}R_{2} \Rightarrow R_{2}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & -\frac{5}{2} & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

- $\frac{5}{2}R_{2} + R_{3} \Rightarrow R_{3}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & -\frac{5}{2}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then in RREF

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & -\frac{5}{2}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

---

$(2)$

- $-2R_{1}+R_{3} \Rightarrow R_{3}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & -2 & 2\\
        0 & 5 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

- $-\frac{1}{2}R_{2} \Rightarrow R_{2}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & 5 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

- $-5R_{2} + R_{3} \Rightarrow R_{3}$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & 5\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then in RREF

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & 5\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

which is different from the RREF in $(1)$

---

Can someone explain why I end up with a different RREF? I thought all RREF are unique, but clearly not in this case. Of course as mentioned earlier, the system has no solutions and both augmented matrices show this but their RREF's are not unique still.

Comment: I'm not sure if RREF are only unique for coefficient matrices instead of augmented matrices. Or if RREF are only unique for consistent systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any RREF must have pivot 1 in each row. Your matrices do not satisfy this condition (look at row 3). So these are not RREFs. RREF of any matrix is unique. It is not a completely trivial statement, but it is a fact.

Comment: My example are augmented matrices, that is in this case, there are more equations(3) then unknowns(2)

Comment: It does not matter. The RREF of **every matrix**, by definition, has pivot 1 in every row. Does not matter where the matrix comes from.

Comment: ? I thought there's only 4 conditions for RREF: 1. first nonzero entry in any nonzero row is 1, 2. zero rows at the bottom, 3. leading 1's to the right in lower than upper rows, 4. zeros below and above each leading 1 of each pivot column. My matrix satisfies all these

Comment: Yes, that is true. Your matrices do not satisfy condition 1.

Comment: There are only two pivot columns. The third column is the column representing the constant on the right side of the linear equation. The number in the last column last row is not supposed to be a leading 1

Comment: The third rows in your matrices do not satisfy condition 1: the first non-zero entries in these rows are not equal to 1.

Comment: I don't think there is supposed to be a leading 1 in row 3, i.e, row 3 does not need to satisfy condition 1. There are only two unknowns which means only two leading 1's. The last row is also a zero row, as the last number of the third row represents the constant not the unknown. Condition 1 only applies to nonzero rows

Comment: I used an online Gauss-Jordan calculator and it gave the same matrix as in my example (2)

Comment: The calculator then does not work correctly. The result is not a RREF. Try Wolfram alpha. It is free and the command rref should work well there.

Comment: Indeed rref{{1,-1,3},{1,1,1},{2,3,6}} is the command in Wolfram alpha and it gives the correct RREF: the identity matrix.

Comment: Augmented matrices are "general" matrices. Condition 1 is a must!

Comment: Yeah you're right. I guess I confused the definition of RREF. Thanks